# Amazon S3 Node.js SDK deleteObjects

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete several objects after copying them to a different folder.
My code is like:

```
    var deleteParam = {
        Bucket: 'frontpass-test',
        Delete: {
            Objects: [
                {Key: '1.txt'},
                {Key: '2.txt'},
                {Key: '3.txt'}
            ]
        }
    };    
    s3.deleteObjects(deleteParam, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log('delete', data);
    });
```

and the returned data is:

```
delete { Deleted: [ { Key: '1.txt' }, { Key: '3.txt' }, { Key: '2.txt' } ],
  Errors: [] }
```

so I assume the deletion is completed. But the objects are still exist in the folder, is there something wrong with my code?

I also tried to delete objects using for loop and s3.deleteObject, but it only delete the last object in my list of files.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var copyParams = {
        Bucket: 'frontpass-test',
        CopySource: 'frontpass-test/unsold/' + files[i].filename,
        Key: 'sold/' + files[i].filename
    };      
    var deleteParam = {
        Bucket: 'frontpass-test',
        Key: 'unsold/' + files[i].filename
    };
    s3.copyObject(copyParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else {
            s3.deleteObject(deleteParam, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                else console.log('delete', data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea on how to delete objects in my case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Well the first example looks good. Do you have object versioning turned on in the bucket? That would keep a copy of a file even after you delete it.

The second example actually contains some bugs that would explain why only the last one gets deleted. Because Node.js is asynchronous, when you hit the `copyObject` function call, the loop iteration ends and goes to the next iteration, not waiting for the callback on `copyObject` to be called. You try to define the `params` variables for each iteration of the loop with the `var` keyword, but because Javascript has function level scope not block level scope, you aren't actually creating new variables on each iteration. You only have one instance of `copyParmas` and `deleteParams`. So you quickly run through the loop and `deleteParams` stays on the value it receives in the last iteration of the loop. Then eventually the callbacks to the `copyObject` calls start firing, and they all call `deleteObject` with `deleteParams` which by now is the *last* one. In order to make multiple asynchronous calls in a loop, I like to use the [`async` library](https://github.com/caolan/async). Using it, you could do the following:

```
async.each(files, function iterator(file, callback) {
    var copyParams = {
        Bucket: 'frontpass-test',
        CopySource: 'frontpass-test/unsold/' + file.filename,
        Key: 'sold/' + file.filename
    };      
    var deleteParam = {
        Bucket: 'frontpass-test',
        Key: 'unsold/' + file.filename
    };
    s3.copyObject(copyParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        else {
            s3.deleteObject(deleteParam, function(err, data) {
                if (err) callback(err)
                else {
                    console.log('delete', data);
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}, function allDone(err) {
    //This gets called when all callbacks are called
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Max! your code totally works! With the first one, I checked the versioning setting, and it is disabled in my bucket, still can not delete objects.

Answer (score 1):

Just had to implement folder rename on top of s3,  I did it as follows: (promise api)

```
    _getDataForItemRename(from, to) {
    return s3.listObjectsV2({Bucket: services.conf.workspace, Prefix: from}).promise()
        .then((data) => {
            const toCopy = [];
            const toRemove = [];
            const s3Contents = Object.assign([], data.Contents);
            // in case of a single dir (with no children)
            if (s3Contents.length === 0) {
                s3Contents.push({Key: from});
            }
            s3Contents.forEach((item) => {
                const copyPromise = s3.copyObject({
                    Bucket: services.conf.workspace,
                    Key: to,
                    CopySource: services.conf.workspace + '/' + item.Key
                }).promise();

                const deletePromise = s3.deleteObjects({
                    Bucket: services.conf.workspace,
                    Delete: {Objects: [{Key: from}]}
                }).promise();

                toCopy.push(copyPromise);
                toRemove.push(deletePromise);
            });

            return {copy: toCopy, remove: toRemove};
        }).catch((err) => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });
}


            return this._getDataForItemRename(_from, _to).then((files) => {
            return Promise.all(files.copy).then(() => {
                return Promise.all(files.remove).then(result => {
                        return result;
                    });
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });
```